# SQL. I need to know if some customer has more than 3 concurrents offers

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How do I SELECT all customers that have more than 3 concurrent offers?

The offer table I have has this columns:

```
custid offerid  inidate        enddate        title
    12,     33, "2016-01-15" , "2016-01-30" , "offer 33" 
    12,     34, "2016-01-18" , "2016-01-22" , "offer 34" 
    12,     35, "2016-01-20" , "2016-01-30" , "offer 35"
    12,     36, "2016-02-01" , "2016-02-30" , "offer 36"
   106,     43, "2016-01-15" , "2016-01-30" , "offer 43" 
   106,     44, "2016-01-18" , "2016-01-22" , "offer 44" 
   106,     45, "2016-01-20" , "2016-01-30" , "offer 45"
   106,     46, "2016-01-01" , "2016-02-30" , "offer 46"
```

Customer 12 has fewer than 4 concurrent offers but Customer 106 has 4 concurrent offers
- from 20th to 22nd will be 4 concurrent offers

```
       15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 01 02 03 04 05 
33  12  |--------------------------------------------|
34  12           |-----------|
35  12                |------------------------------|
36  12                                                    |---------------
43 106  |--------------------------------------------|
44 106           |-----------|
45 106                |------------------------------|
56 106  |-----------------------------------------------------------------
                      ^^^^^^^^
                      106 has 4 concurrent offers
```

Comment: Sorry, first column is offer.custid  nor offer.custis

Comment: check sql aggregate functions like sum , count etc with group by attribute.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select custid, count(offerid) from offer group by custid having count(offerid)  > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of offers for a customer use this query.

```
select count(offerid) from offer where custid = ?;
```

Or list all customers with at least 4 offers:

```
select distinct o1.custid from offer o1 where (select count(o2.offerid) from offer o2 where o1.custid = o2.custid) > 3;
```

If you also want to check for overlapping date intervals, add it to the select count() query:

```
select distinct o1.custid from offer o1 where
 (select count(o2.offerid) from offer o2 where
    o1.custid = o2.custid
    and o1.start_date <= o2.end_date
    and o1.end_date >= o2.start_date) > 3;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but is little more complex I put you one example on the question part. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Select custid, count(*) as numOfOrders from offer
where NOW() between inidate and enddate 
group by custid
having numOfOrders > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
SELECT x.customer_id 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.customer_id = x.customer_id 
   AND y.start_date <= x.end_date 
   AND y.end_date >= x.start_date 
   AND y.offer_id >= x.offer_id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.offer_id 
 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4;
```